# OMNI Short story with unlimited formula racing, activist 'meme bomb'

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for an OMNI Magazine short story about unlimited class car racing - called "Formula Zero" or "Formula X" in the story.

Main character is a cyborg, jacks into his vehicle when racing.

He's in a relationship with an activist who is trying to shut racing down. He agrees to have a 'meme bomb' implanted in himself to this end.

Comment: what is a "meme bomb"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be "Grand Prix" by Simon Ings, published in Omni's June 1993 issue. It is also apparently published in the anthology "Off Limits: Tales of Alien Sex" edited by Ellen Datlow.

From the text:

> Formula Zero is a race for cars, not drivers. It is a vicious testing
>   bed for crackpot ideas, the way Formula One used to be till the
>   nineteen-seventies and the iron rule of Jean Marie Balestre.
>
> Formula One’s rule book ceased to reflect technical progress around
>   that time. Formula Zero was conceived in the nineties as a way round
>   the role book and into the twenty-first century. Anyway, crashes are
>   good for business. My eyes are full of lignocaine. Underlids count off
>   the seconds. I tense my arse and spool the revcounter into the red,
>   just out of my line of focus. I pop the clench plate into my mouth and
>   bite down. The throttle glows green. I blink. The visor snaps down.
>   It’s made of Kevlar. A projector micropored to my head beams eight
>   external views onto the inner surface of the visor then setttles for
>   center-forward.

and

> I’m in a different place. A green hillside. The track is a smooth
>   black nothing under my wheels, swirrling round the hill. I follow it
>   with cybernetic eyes. Gentry in the Ferrari is a blue proximity-danger
>   icon on my left near-side. He cuts me up on the first corner. I’ll use
>   him as a pacemaker. I’m so far ahead of the league table I’d be happy
>   to let him win. But if I don’t pass the post first, then Catharine’s
>   meme-bomb sits in me, waiting for the next victory. It only triggers
>   if I’m race champion. A kind of sick fascination is driving me. That
>   and a hope that the Progamme’s attack on the machismo-oriented Grand
>   Prix might dovetail with my own wish for vengeance on Maureen Havers.